# Tomcat 7.x and code compiled on JDK 1.5

Tags: java, tomcat, jar, tomcat7, war

From [this](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) link looks like minimal Java version supported by Tomcat 7.x is 1.6 but maybe somebody try to check this requirement and use inside webapp jars compiled on JDK 1.5?

Is it works? Or not works at all? Maybe works with limitations?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean with "use inside webapp jars compiled on JDK 1.5". But it seems you mix up two things:

- To run Tomcat 7.x, you'll need at least JRE or JDK 1.6.
- However, you can use any JAR file, which was originally compiled for an earlier Java version as they are upwards compatible.

So if you're interested in using some older jar file, there's no problem.

Comment: The minimum Java version for Tomcat7 is **1.6**, not 1.7